# When using vue router getting error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

When I use the vue-router with my vue

```
let vueRouter = require('vue-router');
Vue.use(vueRouter);
```

I get this msg error:

TypeError: plugin.apply is not a function

plugin.apply(null, args);

When I remove, everything starts to work again.

Comment: Possibly incorrect import? https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2/issues/86

Comment: wich version of vue are you using? Try to replace "let vueRouter = require('vue-router');"  with "import VueRouter from 'vue-router'"

Comment: I tried that and did not work too, I believe that could be because of laravel routes.

Comment: I am using vue 2.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Usually `Vue.use` is used in conjunction with import statements. Here's an example.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

class nameOfClass{
   init(){
     Vue.use(VueRouter);
   }
}
```

Also, vue-router should be in the dependancies section of your package.json